# Using create-react-app for building enterprise level applications

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I want to know whether we can use `create-react-app` for building enterprise level application, does it have any limitations. Or is `create-react-app` meant for beginners who are learning react.

Answer (score 1):

I always start with create-react-app. Even if im doing work for a client. If you find that you need more control over the pipeline later, there is no shame in going with `npm eject`. create react app is not just for beginner and often its more than enough for most people.

Answer (score 1):

It has all you need [for building production-grade](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/cra-template/template/README.md#npm-run-build) front-end.
Even if you'll need to configure something specific you can always use [eject](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/cra-template/template/README.md#npm-run-eject) (rarely needed).

It's just very handy way to generate starter boilerplate, so you don't have to bother with config.